# Why does Ubuntu (and other ubuntu based distros like lubuntu and linux mint) randomly shutdown on my laptop?

Tags: power-management, shutdown, lenovo, amd-processor

I have a lenovo g555 laptop and whenever I try and boot a ubuntu based distro off a usb, it randomly shuts off my PC (Not like a normal shutdown with shutdown loading screen but a like a sudden hard power off). This problem occurs even if I have installed the distro on my harddrive.

In the past I've been able to use the distro for 10 min or so before it would it would do this. Now with the latest distros, It randomly pwers off even before it has fully booted up. My hardware specs are on [this website](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/lenovo-g555-0873-15/4507-3121_7-34022910.html).

Comment: Because it is overheating.  Check that your fans are working and not clogged with dust.

Comment: Try vacuum cleaning the vents...

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if this is a heating problem you can measure the temperature.

Start by checking if you have "lm-sensors" instaled

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}\n' lm-sensors
```

if your output is

```
install ok installed
```

then you can see the temperature by simply tiping

```
sensors
```

otherwise you first have to install "lm-sensors"

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```